# IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10 during numpy matrix broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy

I trying to understand how broadcasting works in numpy.

```
Z = np.random.random((500,10))
y = np.arange(500)
print(Z.shape)
print(y.shape)
Z[range(500), y]
```

I created such example but I get an error:

> IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's an indexing issue, not a broadcasting one.  Most of the values  of `y` are too large.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of array Z is `(500, 10)` which means on axis one(columns) size is 10. But when you use `Z[range(500), y]` you're actually doing `Z[:500, :500]` which is not possible. If you want all the values of Z then use: `Z[:500, :10]` or just `Z`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the goal, but to get rid of the error and keep 500 try this:

```
import numpy as np
n = 500
j = 0 # must be >= 0
i = 0 # must be >= 0
Z = np.random.random((n + i,n + j))
y = np.arange(n)
print(Z.shape)
print(y.shape)
Z[range(n), y]
```